# How to loop through an array to get an item?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

am trying to loop through an array `$permission_ids` to get the value `68` and assign it to a `$manager_role` and store this value in a table `permissions`, but this block of code can not do that?
where did i go wrong?

**

```
foreach ($permission_ids as $permission_id) {
      if($permission_id = 68){
        // attach manager role permission to manager role
        $manager_role->permissions()->attach($permission_id);
      }

    }
```

**

Comment: You need to understand that = != == Try searching for php assign and php compare

Answer (score 1):

I think the comment of @Hoppo is right, you have mistaken the equal operator, use `==` instead of `=` :

```
   foreach ($permission_ids as $permission_id) {
      if($permission_id == 68){
        // attach manager role permission to manager role
        $manager_role->permissions()->attach($permission_id);
      }

    }
```